# SQL SSMS alter table to add new min date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I want to add a new column containing the Min date associated with each ID, data looks like this:

| ID | Datee |
| --- | --- |
| 482566 | 2019-09-13 |
| 3756111 | 2019-12-13 |
| 482566 | 2019-09-14 |
| 482566 | 2019-01-13 |
| 3756111 | 2019-02-13 |
| 3756111 | 2019-16-13 |

I want my data to look like this:

| ID | Datee | First_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 482566 | 2019-09-13 | 2019-01-13 |
| 3756111 | 2019-12-13 | 2019-02-13 |
| 482566 | 2019-09-14 | 2019-01-13 |
| 482566 | 2019-01-13 | 2019-01-13 |
| 3756111 | 2019-02-13 | 2019-02-13 |
| 3756111 | 2019-04-13 | 2019-02-13 |

I've tried the below but no luck, I want to add the column onto my existing table so want to avoid a select function.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable
ADD First_date AS   MIN(Datee)
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: A computed column can only reference the row it is in. If you need to do this, use a `VIEW`; you should not be storing aggregated data in the table.

Comment: @Larnu I wanted to alter the table by adding the calculated column as I need to then refer back to it so I can identify the first_dates in a certain time frame. Is there a way to name the new table so I can do this?

Comment: Again, a computed column can *only* reference values in the same row, so it can't use an aggregate function. Use a `VIEW` is you must have this information readily available.

Comment: How do I use a view in this context?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE XY SET First_date = Y.FDate 
FROM [TABLE_NAME] XY 
 JOIN (SELECT MIN(Datee) as FDate,ID FROM [TABLE_NAME] group by ID) Y
 ON XY.ID=Y.ID
```

This will cater your requirement.
Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: What about when new rows are `INSERT`ed, or existing rows are `UPDATE`d or `DELETE`d? The value of `First_date` could be missing or incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in the question's comments a computed column cannot use an aggregate function, as a computed column can only reference the values of columns in the row it is in. Instead use a `VIEW`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView AS
    
    SELECT ID,
           Datee,
           MIN(Datee) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS FirstDate
    FROM dbo.MyTable;
GO
```

Then you can reference that `VIEW` instead:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       Datee,
       FirstDate
FROM dbo.MyView;
```

Though you *could* create a column and `UPDATE` all the rows, as soon as your data changes the column would be out of date; thus you would need to ensure that the needed rows were `UPDATE`d *every* time a DML statement is run against your table.

There is also the option of using a scalar function, which *would* allow you to use a computed column, *however*, it would have to be an inline scalar function, and such functions are often slow. Thus using a `VIEW` is more than likely going to be the most performant option.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Larnu, you shouldn't be doing this.
But if you actually want to, you could create the Column [First_date] and a trigger to update the table after every insert.

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME] SET First_date = (SELECT MIN(Datee) FROM [TABLE_NAME] GROUP BY ID)
```

Comment: Hi Marcos, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I'm getting a error saying "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression".